Remote JSON parsing (Kotlin)
Sorry for newbie question: I'm new in Android/Kotlin.
There is the RecyclerView in which a remote JSON is being parsed.
Here is an actual code of the Activity with this RecyclerView:
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.io.IOException
import okhttp3.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            val client = OkHttpClient()
    
            val list = ArrayList<ListItem>()
    
            val rcView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_content)
            rcView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            rcView.adapter = MyAdapter(list, this)
            rcView.hasFixedSize()
    
            val request: Request = Request.Builder()
                .url("http://89.111.173.213:8000/api/")
                .build()
    
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
    
                override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                    val strResponse = response.body!!.string()
    
                    val jsonObj: JSONObject = JSONObject(strResponse)
    
                    try {
                        val episodeArray = JSONArray(jsonObj)
                        for (i in 0 until episodeArray.length()) {
                            val episodeDetails = episodeArray.getJSONObject(i)
                            list.add(
                                ListItem(
                                    episodeDetails.getString("pub_date"),
                                    episodeDetails.getString("title"),
                                    episodeDetails.getString("description"),
                                    episodeDetails.getString("youtube_link")
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

Logs (UPDATED):
2024-06-13 18:06:40.228 20892-20892 Perf                    ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           I  Connecting to perf service.
2024-06-13 18:06:40.244 20892-20892 FeatureParser           ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           I  can't find dipper.xml in assets/device_features/,it may be in /system/etc/device_features
2024-06-13 18:06:40.255 20892-20892 libc                    ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           E  Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
2024-06-13 18:06:40.275 20892-20892 AppCompatDelegate       ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           D  Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
2024-06-13 18:06:40.287 20892-20967 Perf                    ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           E  Fail to get file list ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics
2024-06-13 18:06:40.288 20892-20967 Perf                    ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           E  getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2024-06-13 18:06:40.288 20892-20967 Perf                    ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           E  Fail to get file list ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics
2024-06-13 18:06:40.288 20892-20967 Perf                    ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           E  getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2024-06-13 18:06:40.288 20892-20967 Perf                    ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           E  Fail to get file list oat
2024-06-13 18:06:40.288 20892-20967 Perf                    ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           E  getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2024-06-13 18:06:40.306 20892-20892 ForceDarkHelper         ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics activity: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics.StartActivity@f3192c5
2024-06-13 18:06:40.308 20892-20892 ForceDarkHelper         ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics activity: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics.StartActivity@f3192c5
2024-06-13 18:06:40.312 20892-20892 ForceDarkHelper         ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics activity: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics.StartActivity@f3192c5
2024-06-13 18:06:40.313 20892-20892 chatty                  ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           I  uid=10235(ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics) identical 1 line
2024-06-13 18:06:40.313 20892-20892 ForceDarkHelper         ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics activity: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics.StartActivity@f3192c5
2024-06-13 18:06:40.315 20892-20892 .theoaesthetic          ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2024-06-13 18:06:40.317 20892-20892 ForceDarkHelper         ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics activity: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics.StartActivity@f3192c5
2024-06-13 18:06:40.320 20892-20892 ForceDarkHelper         ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics activity: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics.StartActivity@f3192c5
2024-06-13 18:06:40.363 20892-20970 AdrenoGLES              ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           I  QUALCOMM build                   : 033a5b0, I0e419467bc
                                                                                                    Build Date                       : 03/11/20
                                                                                                    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.27.05.01
                                                                                                    Local Branch                     : 
                                                                                                    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.8.3.R1.10.00.00.520.058
                                                                                                    Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                                                    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2024-06-13 18:06:40.363 20892-20970 AdrenoGLES              ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           I  Build Config                     : S P 8.0.11 AArch64
2024-06-13 18:06:40.365 20892-20970 AdrenoGLES              ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           I  PFP: 0x016ee187, ME: 0x00000000
2024-06-13 18:06:40.366 20892-20970 AdrenoUtils             ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           W  <ReadGpuID_from_sysfs:194>: Failed to open /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/gpu_model
2024-06-13 18:06:40.366 20892-20970 AdrenoUtils             ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           W  <ReadGpuID:218>: Failed to read chip ID from gpu_model. Fallback to use the GSL path
2024-06-13 18:06:40.379 20892-20970 Gralloc3                ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           W  mapper 3.x is not supported
2024-06-13 18:06:41.830 20892-20892 Timeline                ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           I  Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:115377135
2024-06-13 18:06:41.842 20892-20892 ActivityThread          ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           W  handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@49bfce
2024-06-13 18:06:41.853 20892-20892 ForceDarkHelper         ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics activity: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics.MainActivity@947c094
2024-06-13 18:06:41.858 20892-20892 chatty                  ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           I  uid=10235(ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics) identical 5 lines
2024-06-13 18:06:41.859 20892-20892 ForceDarkHelper         ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics activity: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics.MainActivity@947c094
2024-06-13 18:06:41.860 20892-20892 ForceDarkHelper         ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics activity: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics.MainActivity@947c094
2024-06-13 18:06:41.864 20892-20892 ForceDarkHelper         ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics activity: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics.MainActivity@947c094
2024-06-13 18:06:41.882 20892-20892 ForceDarkHelper         ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics activity: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics.MainActivity@947c094
2024-06-13 18:06:41.885 20892-20892 chatty                  ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           I  uid=10235(ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics) identical 1 line
2024-06-13 18:06:41.890 20892-20892 ForceDarkHelper         ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics activity: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics.MainActivity@947c094
2024-06-13 18:06:41.902 20892-20892 NetworkSecurityConfig   ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2024-06-13 18:06:41.940 20892-20994 AndroidRuntime          ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           E  FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
                                                                                                    Process: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics, PID: 20892
                                                                                                    java.lang.Error: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id":8,"pub_date":"2024-06-10","title":"Есть ли будущее у теологии постмодерна? (Александр Солонченко)","description":"О теологии постмодерна беседуют философ Алексей Гагинский и богослов Александр Солонченко: кандидат богословия, доцент кафедры богословия МДА, преподаватель факультета церковно-певческого искусства.","mave_link":"https:\/\/theoaesthetics.mave.digital\/ep-4","youtube_link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/4Kimg-BUZN8?si=UvofrS6H8G2PFg8k","audio_file":null},{"id":7,"pub_date":"2024-05-27","title":"Темная теология (Андрей Шишков)","description":"О темной теологии беседуют философ Алексей Гагинский и теолог Андрей Шишков.","mave_link":"https:\/\/theoaesthetics.mave.digital\/ep-3","youtube_link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/ZqQgOcWvzrQ?si=4JENU0PasnLGHVfX","audio_file":null},{"id":6,"pub_date":"2024-05-25","title":"Библия: ирония, радость, деконструкция (Анастасия Медведева)","description":"Что такое ирония? Зачем мы смеемся? Как библейские авторы используют комические приемы? В Библии есть матерная лексика? Почему наше христианство такое разное и можем ли мы говорить о единой христианской традиции? Что такое совесть и превзошли ли мы отцов? Беседуют философ Алексей Гагинский и библеист Анастасия Медведева.","mave_link":"https:\/\/theoaesthetics.mave.digital\/ep-2","youtube_link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/_i4uk3GqjdA?si=eSMkLZsVGCt1VwZv","audio_file":null},{"id":5,"pub_date":"2024-05-20","title":"Теодицея: почему мы страдаем? (о. Стефан Домусчи)","description":"Почему мы страдаем и есть ли смысл в наших страданиях? Почему всеблагой Бог попускает зло? Аморально ли объяснять зло и как мы можем о нем говорить? Какие ответы давали на эти вопросы Христос, Иов, античные философы, Лейбниц, старец Зосима и К.С. Льюис? Беседуют философ Алексей Гагинский и священник Стефан Домусчи.","mave_link":"https:\/\/theoaesthetics.mave.digital\/ep-1","youtube_link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/6RL0MZ0WpZk?si=zehgsWSPbUrjmio_","audio_file":null}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1173)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2024-06-13 18:06:41.940 20892-20994 AndroidRuntime          ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics           E  Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id":8,"pub_date":"2024-06-10","title":"Есть ли будущее у теологии постмодерна? (Александр Солонченко)","description":"О теологии постмодерна беседуют философ Алексей Гагинский и богослов Александр Солонченко: кандидат богословия, доцент кафедры богословия МДА, преподаватель факультета церковно-певческого искусства.","mave_link":"https:\/\/theoaesthetics.mave.digital\/ep-4","youtube_link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/4Kimg-BUZN8?si=UvofrS6H8G2PFg8k","audio_file":null},{"id":7,"pub_date":"2024-05-27","title":"Темная теология (Андрей Шишков)","description":"О темной теологии беседуют философ Алексей Гагинский и теолог Андрей Шишков.","mave_link":"https:\/\/theoaesthetics.mave.digital\/ep-3","youtube_link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/ZqQgOcWvzrQ?si=4JENU0PasnLGHVfX","audio_file":null},{"id":6,"pub_date":"2024-05-25","title":"Библия: ирония, радость, деконструкция (Анастасия Медведева)","description":"Что такое ирония? Зачем мы смеемся? Как библейские авторы используют комические приемы? В Библии есть матерная лексика? Почему наше христианство такое разное и можем ли мы говорить о единой христианской традиции? Что такое совесть и превзошли ли мы отцов? Беседуют философ Алексей Гагинский и библеист Анастасия Медведева.","mave_link":"https:\/\/theoaesthetics.mave.digital\/ep-2","youtube_link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/_i4uk3GqjdA?si=eSMkLZsVGCt1VwZv","audio_file":null},{"id":5,"pub_date":"2024-05-20","title":"Теодицея: почему мы страдаем? (о. Стефан Домусчи)","description":"Почему мы страдаем и есть ли смысл в наших страданиях? Почему всеблагой Бог попускает зло? Аморально ли объяснять зло и как мы можем о нем говорить? Какие ответы давали на эти вопросы Христос, Иов, античные философы, Лейбниц, старец Зосима и К.С. Льюис? Беседуют философ Алексей Гагинский и священник Стефан Домусчи.","mave_link":"https:\/\/theoaesthetics.mave.digital\/ep-1","youtube_link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/6RL0MZ0WpZk?si=zehgsWSPbUrjmio_","audio_file":null}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
                                                                                                        at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
                                                                                                        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:168)
                                                                                                        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:181)
                                                                                                        at ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onResponse(MainActivity.kt:42)
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                                                                                                        ... 2 more
2024-06-13 18:06:44.408  1779-3893  InputDispatcher         system_server                        E  Window handle Window{dbfb085 u0 Application Error: ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics} has no registered input channel
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (20892) for package ru.aspavlov.theoaesthetics ----------------------------

The problem is that the app builds, but the RecyclerView is empty.
UPDATE: I've added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to the AndroidManifest.xml. Now my app crashes. I've updated logs above.

That catch (e: JSONException) that swallows the exception is suspicious; are you sure that's not being hit?

It worked fine when I used this code for parsing JSON from the assets file.

You really should specifically ensure that's not being hit (or onFailure); either check the logs or rethrow the exception wrapped in RuntimeException and see if it crashes.  There's nothing obviously wrong with your adapter, and if, as you say here, you're calling notifyDataSetChanged(), then there's no other obvious problem either.  Also maybe check that the length is > 0.  If it worked fine when parsing from assets, then the issue isn't the adapter; it's the JSON or the HTTP call.

Ok, thanks. Btw, I'm worry with this line: val strResponse = response.body!!.string() val jsonObj: JSONObject = JSONObject(strResponse) try { val episodeArray = JSONArray(jsonObj) <...>}. Is this all right?

Added logs above.

Yep, logs show that it's a connection issue.  See the linked question for information on how to resolve it.

You have to call rcView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to notify your adapter that the data list has changed, it recommended to have your adapter in a separated variable
Set notifyDataSetChanged() on Recyclerview adapter

I've added rcView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged() in try { val episodeArray = JSONArray(jsonObj) <...> }, but the RecyclerView is still empty.

Inside your adapter, which you have overridden, you must also override methods for displaying and outputting information, see here for an example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-recyclerview-in-kotlin/.

I've supplemented my question with the code of MyAdapter.kt.
